# Is it possible to attach a Text Formatter to a TextField directly as an attribute?

Tags: java, javafx

Controller Class

```
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.control.TextFormatter;
import javafx.util.StringConverter;
import javafx.util.converter.IntegerStringConverter;

import java.util.function.UnaryOperator;

public class Controller {
    @FXML
    TextField principal;

    UnaryOperator<TextFormatter.Change> integerFilter = change -> {
        String newText = change.getControlNewText();
        if (newText.matches("-?([1-9][0-9]*)?")) {
            return change;
        }
        return null;
    };
    StringConverter<Integer> converter = new IntegerStringConverter() {
        @Override
        public Integer fromString(String s) {
            if (s.isEmpty()) return 0 ;
            return super.fromString(s);
        }
    };

    TextFormatter<Integer> textFormatter = new TextFormatter<Integer>(converter, 0, integerFilter);
}
```

FXML file

```
<?import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<GridPane fx:controller="sample.Controller"
          xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml" alignment="center" hgap="10" vgap="10">
    <TextField fx:id="principal" textFormatter="textFormatter"/>
</GridPane>
```

So I've got this text field that I want only take numeric input. After digging a bit I found out that a Text Formatter is best suited for the task. I was wondering if there was a way to attach a text formatter(`textFormatter`) as an attribute directly in the FXML file(like `textFormatter="textFormatter"`) cause whenever I try to set it in the controller file, I either get a null pointer exception or it just doesn't work(i.e. the field still takes non-numeric input)

Comment: No, you need to attach it in the controller. If you're getting a `NullPointerException`, you're doing something wrong. Show your attempt to do that.

Comment: OK, I suppose you could actually make it a full-blown property of the controller, and do `<TextField ... textFormatter="${controller.textFormatter}">`, but it's not really the intended approach (and it way more difficult than just setting it directly in the controller).

Comment: @James_D Is there any chance that attaching the Text Formatter in the Start method be the problem cause I got the null pointer problem in another project(I created the current one to test out things)?, if yes, any way to set the text formatter properly in the controller class?

Comment: Your controller shouldn't have a `start()` method. Only the `Application` subclass should have a `start()` method.

Comment: Okay, I think I have messed up a bit. But still how should I attach the text formatter in the controller, like create some method or something?

Comment: Put it in the `initialize()` method. This is all described in the [basic documentation](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/15/javafx.fxml/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#controllers), as well as any FXML tutorial.

Comment: Putting the things `initialize()` worked! Thanks mate for the help, I'm just new to JavaFX